# How to fetch a string from a output in console in java and compare it with the expected value

Tags: java

Below is the code:

```
InputStream in = channelExec.getInputStream();
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
            String line;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {    
                System.out.println(line);               
            }                   
        } catch (JSchException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

The following is my output:

```
Context successfully set
Script started
LXKADMIN|In/OutBoundValidation|-|50149.11065.26960.11788|inbound=OFF|outbound=OFF
inbound=OFF|outbound=OFF
Script complete
STEP 1: COMPLETED
PASSED: step1
```

I want to fetch the line 5 "inbound=OFF|outbound=OFF" and check if its value is matching "inbound=OFF|outbound=OFF" then my test case will pass else it will fail.

The TCL Script is:

```
tcl;
eval {
puts "Script started"

set schemaValidationStr [mql temp query bus LXKADMIN In/OutBoundValidation * select id description dump '|']
puts $schemaValidationStr

set schemaValidation [string range $schemaValidationStr 57 end]
puts $schemaValidation

puts "Script complete"
}
```

Any suggestion will be really helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your question is just how to verify that the output returned by your TCL script, contains a specific line, than you might try this:

```
public static final int CHECK_LINE_NR = 4;
public static final String EXPECTED_LINE_VALUE = "inbound=OFF|outbound=OFF";

public boolean verifyScriptOutput(ChannelExec channel)
  throws IOException
{
  // Check all lines in output
  BufferedReader    reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(channel.getInputStream()));
  String            line;
  int               linenr = 0;
  while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
  {
    linenr++;
    if (linenr == CHECK_LINE_NR)
      return (line.equals(EXPECTED_LINE_VALUE));
  }

  // If we get here, output has less lines
  return (false);

} // verifyScriptOutput
```

Answer (score 0):

The point at which you are reasoning is not possible because you can not access the console and see what is visualized. Instead you should process the input that the console gets, and outputs it, which is the `line` variable in your case.

If for you is enough to see that `inbound=OFF|outbound=OFF` you can search that substring in the `line` like this:

```
if(line.indexOf("inbound=OFF|outbound=OFF") != -1) {
   // you have a match
}
```

Comment: Actually I am accessing a background server using MTPutty by writing a TCL script. I am printing that output in console. But my concern is I want to check if the output returned is as expected. I am adding my tcl script in the main question.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understood the question, but you might try this:

```
public static final int CHECK_LINE_NR = 4;
public static final String CHECK_LINE_VALUE = "inbound=OFF|outbound=OFF";

InputStream in = channelExec.getInputStream();
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
            String line;
            int    linenr;
            boolean line_check_passed;
            linenr = 0;
            line_check_passed = false;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                linenr++;
                if (linenr == CHECK_LINE_NR)
                  line_check_passed = line.equals(CHECK_LINE_VALUE);
                System.out.println(line);               
            }                   
        } catch (JSchException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Comment: I tried this code can you also take a look at my tcl script which is actually returning me the output: inbound=OFF|outbound=OFF but the code shared by you is again returning me the output which I already shared in my question. I am not sure how to verify the text returned is same as what I am expecting.

Comment: I modified the code you shared in your question with some additional lines that verify that the n-th line equals a specified expected value. Apparently, I didn't understand your question....

Answer (score 0):

```
public static boolean check(InputStream in, int line, String expected) throws IOException {
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
    int i = 0;
    String str;

    while ((str = reader.readLine()) != null) {
        if (i < line)
            i++;
        else
            return expected.equals(str);
    }

    return false;
}
```